# Interpretation: Adding quadratic term makes linear term insignificant (OLS regression)

Tags: regression, least-squares, quadratic-form

I'm conducting a multiple OLS regression. My main model contains a significant effect (p < .5) of x on y.

I want to test in a robustness check whether x is related to y in a curvilinear/quadratic way. If I include x as well as x^2 in my model both x and x^2 are insignificant.

However, if I mean-center x and calculate x^2 based on the mean-centered x and then include both variables in my model, x remains significant (p < .5).

How do I interpret these results?

Comment: When do you center? Before or after taking the square?

Comment: Before squaring it.

Comment: I am wondering if you can use ANOVA test between models to compare the models and from there to conclude the significance?

Comment: When non-centred x and x^2 can display non-essential multicollinearity, which can make coefficients insignificant because it blows up SE.

Comment: What you report is not a robustness check.  The idea is to see whether including $x^2$ improves the model enough to lead you to conclude the original model was inadequate. Part of this analysis includes the usual diagnostic plots of residuals.  The other part involves an ANOVA (or comparable calculation) to assess the improvement.  Tests of whether the coefficients are nonzero -- which is what concerns you in this question -- are not directly relevant.

Comment: I think I found the answer to my problem here:
https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqhow-do-i-interpret-the-sign-of-the-quadratic-term-in-a-polynomial-regression/

x = 0 is not in the range of my values. The range of values of x is from 1 to 7. Thus, if I mean-center x = 0 is within the range of values.